# QTextDocument::DrawContents skips resources?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit

I have this setup:

```
// ...

// variable document is a QTextDocument* which has some 'RichText' + 'Images'

QTextEdit textEdit;

textEdit.setDocument(document);

textEdit.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::LineWrapMode::NoWrap);

auto image = QImage(document->size().width(), document->size().height(),
                       QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

image.fill(Qt::transparent);

QPainter painter(&image);

document->drawContents(&painter);
     
// ...
```

I'm doing this to have my text rendered in a long horizontal QImage (hence the "NoWrap" LineWrapMode), so I can select a small part of it at a time with QImage::copy(QRect) and create a scrolling text effect.

The reason I'm doing it this way is that I need to have a QImage at the end which then I would feed its buffer (QImage::bits()) to the hardware that I'm using as my final output.

So it works great, it displays formatted text with fonts and colors and everything except for the images, it seems to skip them, notice the file icon in "result of text with image" picture.

This is text only in editor

[image]

This is result of text only

[image]

This is text with image in editor

[image]

This is result of text with image

[image]

This is how I'm inserting images to my QTextDocument:

```
QImage image(url.toLocalFile());

if (image.isNull())
    return;

image = image.scaledToHeight(getDocumentHeight(), Qt::SmoothTransformation);

auto filename = QUrl(url.fileName());

textEdit->document()->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, filename, image);

textEdit->textCursor().insertImage(filename);
```

So I don't think it's because "DrawContents" fails to find the image resource file or something like this.

What should I do? Is there something that I'm missing? Any kind of help in the matter is highly appreciated! ;)

Comment: @eyllanesc They are in two different classes as they they are part of a much bigger project. anyway, in your case it seems it has worked fine, which i have no idea why, what did you do? I'm on ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code I show how an image should be loaded, then save it to a file, probably the error is that you have not finished painting, for this you must call `painter.end()` or delete painter from memory.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;
    QVBoxLayout vlayout(&widget);
    QTextEdit textEdit;
    QPushButton button("save image");
    QPushButton loadButton("Load and Insert");
    vlayout.addWidget(&loadButton);
    vlayout.addWidget(&textEdit);
    vlayout.addWidget(&button);

    widget.show();

    textEdit.append("some text");

    QObject::connect(&loadButton, &QPushButton::clicked,[&textEdit](){
        QString filename =  QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(&textEdit, "Select", "", "*.png");
        if(!filename.isEmpty()){
            QImage image(filename);
            QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename);
            image = image.scaledToHeight(100, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
            textEdit.document()->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, url, image);
            textEdit.textCursor().insertImage(image);
        }
    });

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&textEdit](){
        QImage image(textEdit.document()->size().toSize() , QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
        image.fill(Qt::transparent);
        QPainter painter(&image);
        textEdit.document()->drawContents(&painter);
        painter.end();
        image.save("image.png");

    });

    return a.exec();
}
```